# ARKit : SCNBox moves with camera

Tags: ios, opencv, augmented-reality, arkit, scnnode

I am drawing huge box of length 20 meters width 0.5 meters and height 0.5 meters which is 2 meters away from the origin.

Box rendered properly without any issues. However box look smaller and seems to be spread across less length compared to actual length. Upon moving the device camera, box also moves in the direction of camera. Upon coming back to origin position, again box looks smaller. Any leads why this happens with ARKit screen rendering. Can any fix be applied to resolve this issue?

```
let node = SCNNode()
node.geometry = SCNBox(width: 0.5, height: 0.5, length: 20.0, chamferRadius: 0.01)
```

Comment: How you set up scene configuration? Did you wait until valid state? Did ARKit template project works fine for you?

Comment: @MichaelVorontsov ARKit template project looks good from me. Yes, I waited until valid state. 
configuration = ARWorldTrackingConfiguration()
configuration.planeDetection = .horizontal

Comment: Then I recommend to compare your setup with template project. You can try to replace spaciship with you box. Or provide code in question here.